# strtok_r() in c is apparently skipping tokens?

Tags: c, multithreading, strtok

I have a program meant to take in a file (**WarandPeace.txt**), read it into a given number of threads, and process it into a list of words and a count of each word. I open the file separately in each thread, read a chunk of it into a string with `pread()`, then break the string into tokens with `strtok_r()`. I add the tokens to the list, incrementing where I find the same token repeated, and then finally combine the lists from each thread into a single list.

My problem is that as far as I can tell `strtok_r` is failing to count various words accurately for some reason. As an example, I know the word `princess` occurs 937 times in the file, but in my code `strtok_r` only appears to pick it up about 300 times. The error persists irrespective of how many threads I run the program with. It doesn't seem to be a problem with adding tokens to the list because when I do a `printf("%s,%i", token, count)` as I process the string I get the same reduced count.

**EDIT:**

Here is a minimum compilable snippet that reproduces the problem

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

char *delim = "\"\'.“”‘’?:;-,—*($%)! \t\n\x0A\r";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char* fileName = "WarAndPeace.txt";

    int fileID = open(fileName, O_RDONLY);

    off_t fileSize = lseek(fileID, 0, SEEK_END);

    printf("\nfilesize: %ld\n", fileSize);

    char readFromFile[fileSize + 1];

    readFromFile[fileSize] = '\0';

    ssize_t readResult = pread(fileID, readFromFile, fileSize, 0);

    char *token;
    char *rest = readFromFile;
    char *remaining;

    printf("\nsize of string being fed to strtok_r(): %ld", strlen(rest));

    token = strtok_r(rest, delim, &remaining);
    int counter = 0;
    if (strcmp(token, "princess") == 0) {
        counter++;
        printf("\ntoken - %s, count - %i\n", token, counter);
    }
    
    while ((token = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &remaining))) {
        if (strcmp(token, "princess") == 0) {
            counter++;
            printf("\ntoken - %s, count - %i\n", token, counter);
        }
    }
}
```

This should count princess 937 times but only counts it 330 times.

Note: If you want to test this yourself, you'll need to download [War and Peace](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2600/pg2600.txt) and rename it **WarAndPeace.txt**.

Here's my full program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

// You may find this Useful
char * delim = "\"\'.“”‘’?:;-,—*($%)! \t\n\x0A\r";

// This struct holds a word from the file and its count, as well as a pointer
// to another word, in order to create a singly-linked list of words

struct Word {
    char * word;
    int count;
    struct Word * next;
};
typedef struct Word Word;

// This struct holds the information passed to each thread as well as a pointer
// to the final shared list to be created, one of these will be created
// for each thread

struct ThreadRecord {
    int totalThreads;
    int thisThread;
    Word ** listHead;
    char * fileName;
};

typedef struct ThreadRecord ThreadRecord;

// This is the function passed into each thread that does the main work of 
// the program
void * readFile( void * threadRecordVoid );

// this function runs after the threads have returned and sorts the completed
// list by size of count 
void sortListBySize( Word ** listHead );

// This function runs as part of readFile and combines the multiple thread's
// list of words into a single combined list of words
void combineList (Word ** combinedList, Word ** transferList);


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    //***TO DO***  Look at arguments, open file, divide by threads
    //             Allocate and Initialize and storage structures

    char * fileName = argv[1];

    char * ptr;
    
    int threadCount = (int)strtol(argv[2], &ptr, 10);

    // The list pointer we pass to every thread to make our combined list

    Word * listHead = NULL;

    // A threadRecord created for every thread passing in that thread's number
    // the total number of threads and the filename, which will allow each
    // thread to access the file at the appropriate place.
    
    ThreadRecord * threadRecords[threadCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
        threadRecords[i] = malloc(sizeof(ThreadRecord));
        threadRecords[i]->totalThreads = threadCount;
        threadRecords[i]->thisThread = i;
        threadRecords[i]->fileName = fileName;
        threadRecords[i]->listHead = &listHead;
    }
    

    //**************************************************************
    // DO NOT CHANGE THIS BLOCK
    //Time stamp start
    struct timespec startTime;
    struct timespec endTime;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &startTime);
    //**************************************************************
    // *** TO DO ***  start your thread processing
    //                wait for the threads to finish
    
    


    pthread_t threads[threadCount];
    int threadReturn[threadCount];

    // We run our threads, calling readFile

    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
        threadReturn[i] = pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, readFile, (void*) threadRecords[i]);
    }

    // we wait on our threads

    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    // If a thread returns an error, we say so and exit

    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
        if (threadReturn[i] > 0) {
            printf("Thread %d returned an error, quitting", i);
            return 2;
        }
    }



    // ***TO DO *** Process TOP 10 and display


    // we sort the master list of threads

    sortListBySize(threadRecords[0]->listHead);

    // We print the top 10 threads

    printf("\nThe top 10 words - %d threads\n", threadCount);
    Word * printList = *threadRecords[0]->listHead;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && printList != NULL; i++){
        printf("\nWord - %s, count - %d\n", printList->word, printList->count);
        printList = printList->next;
    }
    

    //**************************************************************
    // DO NOT CHANGE THIS BLOCK
    //Clock output
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &endTime);
    time_t sec = endTime.tv_sec - startTime.tv_sec;
    long n_sec = endTime.tv_nsec - startTime.tv_nsec;
    if (endTime.tv_nsec < startTime.tv_nsec)
        {
        --sec;
        n_sec = n_sec + 1000000000L;
        }

    printf("Total Time was %ld.%09ld seconds\n", sec, n_sec);
    //**************************************************************


    // ***TO DO *** cleanup

    // here we free the list memory
    Word * deleteList = *threadRecords[0]->listHead;

    while(deleteList){
        Word * tempWord = deleteList;
        deleteList = deleteList->next;
        free(tempWord->word);
        tempWord->word = NULL;
        free(tempWord);
        tempWord = NULL;
    }

    // here we free the threadRecord memory

    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
        free(threadRecords[i]);
        threadRecords[i] = NULL;
    }



}


// This is the function that runs for every thread, it divides up the file into a chunk for each
// thread, sorts that chunk of the file into words and totals of occurrences (sorting the words
// alphabetically), then it merges every thread's list into a combined list using mutex locks
// to ensure data safety. The merged list is also sorted, this way the sort step in which the
// threads can run independently is bumped from n to nlogn but the merge step in which the
// threads are limited by the lock is reduced from n^2 to nlogn, resulting in code that gets
// more efficient with more threads

void * readFile (void * threadRecordVoid){

    // we recover the voided threadRecord that contains our passthrough data
    ThreadRecord * threadRecord = (ThreadRecord *)threadRecordVoid;

    // we open the file
    int fileID = open(threadRecord->fileName, O_RDONLY);

    // we get the filesize
    off_t fileSize = lseek(fileID, 0, SEEK_END);

    printf("\nfilesize: %ld\n", fileSize);

    // we calculate how big each thread's chunk of the filesize will be
    long fileChunkSize = fileSize / threadRecord->totalThreads;

    printf("\nchunk size: %ld\n", fileChunkSize);

    // we create the array we'll use to read from the file and end it
    // with a null terminator
    char readFromFile[fileChunkSize + 1];

    readFromFile[fileChunkSize] = '\0';

    // we read from the file
    ssize_t readResult = pread(fileID, 
        readFromFile, 
        fileChunkSize, 
        fileChunkSize * threadRecord->thisThread);

    /*
    char sample[1000];
    sample[999] = '\0';
    strncpy(sample, readFromFile, 999);
    printf("\nSample Text of War and Peace:\n%s\n", sample);
    */

    // Here we begin breaking up the file and storing it as individual words
    // with counts. We use strtok_r (because it's threadsafe) to read a word
    // from the string we created from our thread's chunk of the file. We
    // handle that word in various ways depending on how it sorts into the list.
    // We move on to the next word until we're out of words. Then we're done and we
    // move on ot the merge step.

    // We start will a null node.

    Word * threadListHead = NULL;

    char* token;
    char* rest = readFromFile;

    // We get a token from strtok_r and check if it's null
    int counter = 0;
    while ((token = strtok_r(rest, delim, &rest)) ){
        // We only do something with the token if it's at least six chars
        if (strcmp(token, "princess") == 0) {
            counter++;
            printf("\ntoken - %s, count - %i\n", token, counter);
        }
        if (strlen(token) >= 6){
            // This handles the very first node created in the list
            if (threadListHead == NULL){
                threadListHead = malloc(sizeof(Word));
                threadListHead->word = malloc(sizeof(token));
                strcpy(threadListHead->word,token);
                threadListHead->count = 1;
                threadListHead->next = NULL;
            }
            // This handles count increases at the head node
            else if (strcmp(threadListHead->word, token) == 0) {
                threadListHead->count++;
            }
            // This handles the case of whether a word is lower in the
            // list than the head, in which case we create a new head
            else if (strcmp(threadListHead->word, token) > 0) {
                Word * newWord = malloc(sizeof(Word));
                newWord->word = malloc(sizeof(token));
                strcpy(newWord->word, token);
                newWord->count = 1;
                newWord->next = threadListHead;
                threadListHead = newWord;
            }
            // here we handle traversing the list after the head
            else {
                Word * currWord = threadListHead;
                
                // We traverse the list while the next word is not null and the next word
                // is smaller than the current token
                while(currWord->next != NULL && strcmp(currWord->next->word, token) < 0) {
                currWord = currWord->next;
                }    
                
                // If we get to null, we add a new node on the end of the list
                if (currWord->next == NULL){
                    
                    currWord->next = malloc(sizeof(Word));
                    currWord = currWord->next;
                    currWord->next = NULL;  
                    currWord->word = malloc(sizeof(token));
                    strcpy(currWord->word, token);  
                    currWord->count = 1;
                    if(strcmp(currWord->word, "princess") == 0){
                        printf("\nAdding at end\n%s - count %d", 
                            currWord->word, currWord->count);
                    }
                }
                // if we have a matching word, we increase the count
                else if (strcmp(currWord->next->word, token) == 0) {
                    
                    currWord->next->count++;
                    /*
                    if(strcmp(currWord->next->word, "princess") == 0){
                        printf("\nincrementing count\n%s - count %d", 
                            currWord->next->word, currWord->next->count);
                    }                    
                    */
                }
                // if we have a node that matches a particular position in the list, we 
                // insert a new node into that position
                else if (strcmp(currWord->next->word, token) > 0) {
                    
                    Word * newWord = malloc(sizeof(Word));
                    newWord->word = malloc(sizeof(token));
                    strcpy(newWord->word, token);
                    newWord->count = 1;
                    newWord->next = currWord->next;
                    currWord->next = newWord;
                    if(strcmp(currWord->next->word, "princess") == 0){
                        printf("\ninserting into list\n%s - count %d", 
                            currWord->next->word, currWord->next->count);
                    }                    
                }
                else {
                    printf("\nerror storing token - %s\n", token);
                }
            }



        }
        

    }

    // Here we call the function that combines the sorted lists into a single list
    
    combineList(threadRecord->listHead, &threadListHead);



    /*
    Word * transferHead = threadListHead;


    while(transferHead) {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
        if ((*threadRecord->listHead) == NULL){
            Word * tempWord = transferHead;
            transferHead = transferHead->next;
            tempWord->next = NULL;
            *threadRecord->listHead = tempWord;
        }
        else if (strcmp((*threadRecord->listHead)->word, transferHead->word) == 0){
            Word * tempWord = transferHead;
            transferHead = transferHead->next;
            (*threadRecord->listHead)->count += tempWord->count;
            free(tempWord->word);
            tempWord->word = NULL;
            free(tempWord);
            tempWord = NULL;

            

        }
        else if (strcmp((*threadRecord->listHead)->word, transferHead->word) > 0){

            Word * tempWord = transferHead;
            transferHead = transferHead->next;
            tempWord->next = *threadRecord->listHead;
            *threadRecord->listHead = tempWord;




        }
        else {
            Word * currWord = *threadRecord->listHead;

            

            while(currWord->next != NULL && strcmp(currWord->next->word, transferHead->word) < 0){
                currWord = currWord->next;
            }
            if (currWord->next == NULL){
                //printf("segfault? currWord->next == NULL");

                Word * tempWord = transferHead;
                transferHead = transferHead->next;
                tempWord->next = NULL;
                currWord->next = tempWord;

            } 
            else if (strcmp(currWord->next->word, transferHead->word) == 0){
                //printf("segfault? strcmp(currWord->next->word, transferHead->word) == 0");
                Word * tempWord = transferHead;
                transferHead = transferHead->next;
                currWord->next->count = currWord->next->count + tempWord->count;
                free(tempWord->word);
                tempWord->word = NULL;
                free(tempWord);
                tempWord = NULL;

            }
 
            else if (strcmp(currWord->next->word, transferHead->word) > 0)
            {
                //printf("segfault? strcmp(currWord->next->word, transferHead->word) > 0");
                Word * tempWord = transferHead;
                transferHead = transferHead->next;
                tempWord->next = currWord->next;
                currWord->next = tempWord;


            }
             
            else{
                printf("\nError transferring word - %s\n", transferHead->word);

            }
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
        
    }
    */

    /*
    printf("\nThread %d - first 10 of threadRecord\n", threadRecord->thisThread);

    printList = *threadRecord->listHead;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10 && printList != NULL; i++){
        printf("\nword - %s - count - %d\n", printList->word, printList->count);
        printList = printList->next;
    }
    */

    /*
    while(threadListHead){
        Word * toDelete = threadListHead;
        threadListHead = threadListHead->next;
        free(toDelete);
        toDelete = NULL;
    }
    */
}

// This is the function that readFile runs to combine the sorted lists from each
// thread into a single combined list. It pulls nodes directly out of the 
// existing lists and enters them into the new list, deleting duplicate entries
// after adding their counts to the existing entry's count

void combineList (Word ** combinedList, Word ** transferList){
    Word * transferHead = *transferList;

    while(transferHead) {
        // We use a mutex lock here to control access to the combined list since
        // writes to it need to be thread safe
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
        
        // Here we handle creating the first node in the previously empty list
        if ((*combinedList) == NULL){
            Word * tempWord = transferHead;
            transferHead = transferHead->next;
            tempWord->next = NULL;
            *combinedList = tempWord;
        }
        // next we handle nodes that match the head, deleting the nodes after we've
        // added in the count
        else if (strcmp((*combinedList)->word, transferHead->word) == 0){
            Word * tempWord = transferHead;
            transferHead = transferHead->next;
            (*combinedList)->count += tempWord->count;
            free(tempWord->word);
            tempWord->word = NULL;
            free(tempWord);
            tempWord = NULL;

        }
        // Next we handle words that go before the head by creating a new head and
        // tagging the rest of the list onto it
        else if (strcmp((*combinedList)->word, transferHead->word) > 0){

            Word * tempWord = transferHead;
            transferHead = transferHead->next;
            tempWord->next = *combinedList;
            *combinedList = tempWord;

        }
        // Next we handle traversal of the list beyond the head
        else {
            Word * currWord = *combinedList;

            // We search the list while the next pointer is not null and is smaller than the
            // current search term
            while(currWord->next != NULL 
                && strcmp(
                    currWord->next->word, 
                    transferHead->word) < 0){
                currWord = currWord->next;
            }
            // if we reach null, we insert the node at the end and make its next pointer the new
            // NULL
            if (currWord->next == NULL){

                Word * tempWord = transferHead;
                transferHead = transferHead->next;
                tempWord->next = NULL;
                currWord->next = tempWord;

                if(strcmp("princess", tempWord->word) == 0){
                    printf("\ninserting at end of list\n%s - count %d",
                        tempWord->word,
                        tempWord->count);
                }

            } 
            // if the word is a match, we add the count to the list and delete the transfer node
            else if (strcmp(currWord->next->word, transferHead->word) == 0){
                Word * tempWord = transferHead;
                transferHead = transferHead->next;
                currWord->next->count = currWord->next->count + tempWord->count;
                if(strcmp("princess", tempWord->word) == 0){
                    printf("\nadding to existing node\n%s - count %d",
                        currWord->next->word,
                        currWord->next->count);
                }
                free(tempWord->word);
                tempWord->word = NULL;
                free(tempWord);
                tempWord = NULL;


            }
            // if the word slots in earlier in the list, we add the node in that location
            else if (strcmp(currWord->next->word, transferHead->word) > 0)
            {
                Word * tempWord = transferHead;
                transferHead = transferHead->next;
                tempWord->next = currWord->next;
                currWord->next = tempWord;
                if(strcmp("princess", tempWord->word) == 0){
                    printf("\ninserting into list\n%s - count %d",
                        tempWord->word,
                        tempWord->count);
                }

            }
             
            else{
                printf("\nError transferring word - %s\n", transferHead->word);

            }
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
        
    }


}

// This function sorts the completed list by the size of the count using an insertion
// sort. Note: May come back to this later to sort by something with better time
// complexity to improve program performance

void sortListBySize ( Word ** listHead ){
    Word * sortedList = NULL;

    Word * currListHead = *listHead;
    while ( currListHead) {
        // Here we handle the first node in the sorted list, taking it from the 
        // unsorted list
        if (sortedList == NULL){
            sortedList = currListHead;
            currListHead = currListHead->next;
            sortedList->next = NULL;
        }
        // Here we handle nodes that sort before the list head, making them
        // the new list head and tacking the list on after them
        else if (sortedList->count <= currListHead->count){
            Word * tempWord = currListHead;
            currListHead = currListHead -> next;
            tempWord->next = sortedList;
            sortedList = tempWord;
        }
        // Here we handle sorted list traversal beyond the head
        else {
            Word * currWord = sortedList;
            // We advance in the sorted list while the next pointer doesn't equal null
            // and its count is greater than the unsorted list node's count
            while(currWord->next != NULL && currWord->next->count > currListHead->count){
                currWord = currWord->next;
            }
            // If we reach null, we insert the pointer at the end and set its next
            // pointer to null
            if (currWord->next == NULL) {
                Word * tempWord = currListHead;
                currListHead = currListHead->next;
                tempWord->next = NULL;
                currWord->next = tempWord;
            }
            // If we reach a position in the list earlier than null, we insert the node
            // at that position
            else if (currWord->next->count <= currListHead->count){
                Word * tempWord = currListHead;
                currListHead = currListHead->next;
                tempWord->next = currWord->next;
                currWord->next = tempWord;
            }
            
        }
    }

    // We set the listHead to the sortedList pointer, setting the list to the
    // sorted list

    *listHead = sortedList;

}
```

The correct results for the top 10 threads should be as follows:

```
Number 1 is Pierre with a count of 1963
Number 2 is Prince with a count of 1928
Number 3 is Natásha with a count of 1212
Number 4 is Andrew with a count of 1143
Number 5 is himself with a count of 1020
Number 6 is princess with a count of 916
Number 7 is French with a count of 881
Number 8 is before with a count of 833
Number 9 is Rostóv with a count of 776
Number 10 is thought with a count of 767
```

My results are as follows:

```
Word - Pierre, count - 1963

Word - Prince, count - 1577

Word - Natásha, count - 1213

Word - Andrew, count - 1143

Word - himself, count - 1017

Word - French, count - 881

Word - before, count - 779

Word - Rostóv, count - 776

Word - thought, count - 766

Word - CHAPTER, count - 730
```

Does anyone know what the source of the error could be?

Comment: "*Here's my full program*" - that is WAY too much code to ask anyone here to look through trying to diagnose your issue. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (emphasis on **minimal**), just the absolute bare-bones code needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: So far I spotted a few bugs but they don't really explain the described behavior. Question: Is the result always the same or do you get different results when running the program several times?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the suggestion, I've updated with that.

Comment: @SupportUkraine the result is always the same, for example I always get a princess count of 330, and the top ten results of the full program are always as specified below.

Comment: In the "minimum " code example,  if you print `readResult` and `fileSize` do you get the expected value? And what is that value?

Comment: `readResult` is too big to output and read in the console (unless you want to read all of War and Peace) but I do confirm in the code that the size is as expected / matches the size of `fileSize`.

Comment: @fifthfiend `readResult` is just a number.... you can print it, no problem. And you can print `fileSize` as well. What are the values?  Notice: I'm **not** asking for `readFromFile`

Comment: `filesize: 3359549`

`readResult - 3359549`

Comment: okay. That's quite a big chunck of memory to put on the stack. As far as I recall Linux systems normally has 8M stack while Windows has 1M. You should use dynamic allocation. But for testing you could create a big **global** array instead. Like: `char readFromFile[4000000];` That said, I doubt that is the problem.

Comment: Try: `char* remaining = NULL;`

Comment: Dynamic allocation? Like `char * readFromFile = malloc(fileSize)`?

Comment: No change with `char* remaining = NULL;`

Comment: I like the idea of the program; having some familiarity with the book myself. Do consider posting the code with a sample test program that exercises it's validity at codereview.com once it is working and finished; your code would benefit from it.

Comment: @fifthfiend Re dynamic allocation you need to add one. Like `char * readFromFile = malloc(fileSize + 1);`

Answer (score 3):

The single threaded code that you call the "minimum compilable snippet" is doing it correct.

It is your expectations that are wrong.

You say you expect "princess" 937 times. I don't know how you got that number but my guess is that you opened the text file in a browser like Chrome and searched for "princess". When I do that I do see a total of 937.

But...

This includes

```
princess
Princess
princesses
Princesses
```

as the browser search 1) isn't case sensitive and 2) isn't working with whole words.

Using `grep` (on linux) I get

```
grep princess -cw WarAndPeace.txt
330
```

just like your program.

So I made a little hack (note: it's not the way to do it in real code):

```
token = strtok_r(rest, delim, &remaining);
int counter = 0;
if (token[0] == 'P') token[0] = 'p';      // HACK !!
if (strncmp(token, "princess", 8) == 0){  // HACK !!
    counter++;
    printf("\ntoken - %s, count - %i\n", token, counter);
}

while ((token = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &remaining)) ){
  if (token[0] == 'P') token[0] = 'p';      // HACK !!
  if (strncmp(token, "princess", 8) == 0) { // HACK !!
        counter++;
        printf("\ntoken - %s, count - %i\n", token, counter);
    }
}
```

and now I get 937

For your **multi-thread** code this line:

```
long fileChunkSize = fileSize / threadRecord->totalThreads;
```

is bad. You do an integer division so the result is truncated. If the file is 209 bytes and you have 10 threads you get 209/10 = 20. So the last 9 bytes isn't handled.

Further, it may/will happen that you split a word so that one thread gets "prin" and the next thread gets "cess". And you won't be able to count correctly. You need a more advanced way of splitting the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ssize_t readResult = pread(fileID, 
        readFromFile, 
        fileChunkSize, 
        fileChunkSize * threadRecord->thisThread);
```

man: pread() reads "up to" count bytes from file descriptor fd

Check your return. You probably have a short read.

It looks like you tried to debug with "princess" and short circuited your logic and found that the problem is in `strtok_r`. Normally I'd be complaining about reduce your code to a much smaller example but I'm pretty sure you manually verified `counter` has the wrong value even though the code that looks at is missing right now. This doesn't leave much left to find but the short read.

Comment: I checked the size of `rest` with `strlen` and got the expected result so it looks like pread is reading everything it should. Sorry if I posted too much of my code, I can edit it to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the code sample @Support Ukraine provided, we can reduce code duplicity and use POSIX's `strncasecmp()` for a case-insensitive comparison. (Yes, `strncasecmp()` is not in the C standard, but we are using POSIX threads here, so I doubt that would be a problem).

> The strcasecmp() function performs a byte-by-byte comparison of
> the strings s1 and s2, ignoring the case of the characters.
>
> The strncasecmp() function is similar, except that it compares no
> more than n bytes of s1 and s2.

```
if (!strncasecmp (token, "princess", 8)) {
    count++;
}
```

And the duplicated calls to `strtok_r()` can be eliminated with a `for` loop:

```
for (char *token = rest; token = strtok_r (token, delim, &remaining); token = 0) {
    if (!strncasecmp (token, "princess", 8) {
        count++;
    }
}

— @Fe203
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in the code:

- `while ((token = strtok_r(rest, delim, &rest)) ){` is incorrect. The context argument for `strtok_r` is separate from the initial pointer to the string.  You should write:

  ```
   char *rest = readFromFile;
   char *context;
   char *token;
   while ((token = strtok_r(rest, delim, &context))) {
       rest = NULL;  // for the next iteration
       ...
  ```
- `if (strcmp(token, "princess") == 0)` only counts instances of `princess` that in all lowercase and form a full word.  Neither `Princess` nor `princesses` will be counted.
- `currWord->word = malloc(sizeof(token));` only allocated the space for the size of a pointer, not a copy of the string. You should use `currWord->word = strdup(token);`
- same problem with `threadListHead->word = malloc(sizeof(token));`
- `char readFromFile[fileChunkSize + 1];` allocates a large buffer on the thread stack.  This may be too large, eg: 3.2 MB for a single thread operation.  You should use `malloc()`.
- splitting the file into chunks, one for each thread causes problems at the chunk boundaries: any word overlapping chunk boundaries will be split into 2 separate words for counting.
- the algorithms for would counting and sorting are very inefficient, lienar scans in the list of words yields a quadratic time complexity, which the multi-thread operation cannot cure.  Using hash tables is highly recommended for this task.